# What could be the reason for external video to not link?

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks

Tinypic link for video in EDIT3 in my answer does not work. What could be the reason?(insecure?)

[Tractrix post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184595/is-friction-necessary-for-a-tractrix-curve/2184673#2184673)

Comment: Where did you get the link from? When you edit, it starts with `http` rather than the `https` that the working images start with. Did you upload it yourself, from SE, recently?

Comment: It does work for me (it just doesn't display it inline in your answer, but that's expected).

Comment: @pjs36  Video link is not possible here ( in Math SE). So I made an IPad video of dragged magnet. Uploaded via  tinypic video to link its URL at  text.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks. Changing  video to *vimeo*  works, at least for now.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reloaded video via ***Vimeo*** instead of tinypic and it now works alright.

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to accept this answer (so the question doesn't get bumped to the homepage again).

Comment: Thanks. You mean accepting own answer? Wondering about appropriateness, anyway I can also unaccept if viewed not in order.

Comment: Accepting own answer is actually encouraged (under the appropriate circumstances) and anyway on meta there are no points at stake so no one is likely to be upset.